# How to read a font file's properties using C#/net6.0?

Tags: c#, .net-core, fonts, .net-6.0

I'm building a Font Management WebApi that uploads font file (either otf, ttf or ttc) via an IFormFile. I need to inspect the file (or preferably the fileStream) at time of upload and read the normal properties of the font, such as Name, Family, Style and Version, so that I can verify conflicts against other fonts in the system.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This github repository should help

https://github.com/LayoutFarm/Typography/blob/master/Typography.OpenFont/OpenFontReader.cs